# Oracle SQL Count and Avg in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the table PATIENT_SESSIONS with these fields:

```
PATIENT_ID,
Session_Date,
Session_Status (Scheduled, Completed, Canceled),
PATIENT_Paid_Date,
Amount
```

I want from this table to get for each patient_id the last session_date, the average between PATIENT_Paid_Date and Session_Date, the max(Amount) and count of Complete sessions in a single query.
Is it possible?

Comment: You need to edit your question and show sample table data (as a table) and expected output and the table column types, and your attempt.  See [mcve]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Sounds like a simple aggregation query to me (except maybe for the completed session count, for which you need conditional aggregation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing `PATIENT_ID` is what you mean by "for each `student_id`"?

```
SELECT
   PATIENT_ID
 , MAX(Session_Date) AS last_session_date
 , AVG(Session_Date - PATIENT_Paid_Date) AS avg_between_dates 
-- not sure if this is what you want without seeing sample data
 , MAX(Amount) AS max_amount
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Session_Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     AS count_complete_sessions
FROM PATIENT_SESSIONS
GROUP BY PATIENT_ID
```

Should be possible.